# How to update view with API Call data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to update my view using data received from a `URLSession` request.

I can get the data to print to the console with the `onAppear`:

```
struct HomeTab: View {

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 1) {
        Text(//I want the data to show here)
        Spacer()
    }.padding()

   .onAppear {
    callDevices().getDevices { (response) in
        print(response.devices[0].parentRelations[0].displayName)
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to actually show the data in my view? I want the data to be updated on every `onAppear`.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my model:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let devices: [Device]
}

// MARK: - Device
struct Device: Codable {
    let name, type, assignee: String
    let parentRelations: [ParentRelation]
}

// MARK: - ParentRelation
struct ParentRelation: Codable {
    let parent, displayName: String
}
```

and my API Class:

```
class callDevices {
    private var project_id: String = "redacted"
    func getDevices(completion: @escaping (Welcome) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://redacted") else {return}
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("redacted", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
            guard let data = data else {print("empty data"); return }

            let theData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(theData)
            }
            
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the completion handler and take advantage of the `Combine` framework and a `@Published` property.

In your class adopt `ObservableObject` and declare a `@Published` property `devices`. Assign the devices array to the property in the closure

```
import Combine

class CallDevices : ObservableObject {
    private var project_id: String = "redacted"
 
    @Published var devices = [Device]() 

    func getDevices() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://redacted") else {return}
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("redacted", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
            // guard let data = data else {print("empty data"); return }

            let theData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.devices = theData.devices
            }
            
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

In the view declare a reference to the observable class, in `onAppear` call `getDevices()`. The view will be updated after `devices` has been modified

```
struct HomeTab: View {

    @StateObject var callDevices = CallDevices()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 1) {
            Text(callDevices.devices.first?.parentRelations.first?.displayName ?? "")
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    
       .onAppear {
           callDevices.getDevices()  
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of removing the completion handler. When is it better to use a completion handler over combine?

Comment: In a SwiftUI environment to drive a view not at all.

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to loop through my data to show it rather than explicitly showing one bit of data (`allDevices.devices.first?.parentRelations.first?.displayName ?? ""`) How could I achieve that? Is it better to post a new question?

Comment: Please learn the basics of SwiftUI. I recommend [100 Days of SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui). There is `List` and/or `ForEach`